# nested accordian menu not working properly

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-accordion

i need nested accordian menu so that i have followed this tutorial from this  [link](http://perishablepress.com/jquery-accordion-menu-tutorial/). i have changed the jquery

```
$('li a').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var ullist = $(this).parent().children('ul:first');
ullist.slideToggle(); });
```

it is working but if i click child,parent can not be hide. can any one give me solution. please check this (http://jsfiddle.net/LgejL4oh/3/)

thank you

Comment: Would you be more specific on what you want? So, When you click the child you want to hide the parent or the functionality is not working? Fiddle is working fine. So, Please add replication step.

Comment: thanks for quick replying, what i need means i.e in fiddle first i click Products,second i click Company in this case Products should be hide and Company should be show. same thing will do inside child also.

Comment: what i exactly need means like this( http://jsfiddle.net/Xanetia/8kz4m/) but they are using div in jquery . but i need unorderlist(ul) and list(li)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I managed to make it work. I make it work by doing ,

First Check if the Element being clicked has child `ul:first` **hidden or not**.

1. If `visible` skip the toggle functionality(Means you are toggling on/off the same tab)
2. else `toggle` all the other `visible` element except the current one(So, If Company is previously visible hide it and display the current clicked tab )

So, Here is the code ,

```
if (!$(this).parent().children('ul:first').is(":visible")) {
    $(this).parent().parent().find("li").children('ul:visible').slideToggle();
 }
var ullist = $(this).parent().children('ul:first');
ullist.slideToggle();
```

#### And here is the [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LgejL4oh/8/)